# Saving time to database in the absence of Zone information

Tags: postgresql, java-time

I process a TEXT log file that contains, among other items, date in this form: 'January 20, 2021 5:26:19 pm'.

I don't have zone information. The system runs in complete isolation, such as offline mode, or no connectivity to the internet. Zero connectivity to the outside world.

I want to save this information to the database for further time comparison such look at logs which are greater than this time.
So, I save it to the POSTGRES database in a column of type timestamp.
When needed I retrieve from database convert to LocalDataTime and use it.

What is the right way or better way of saving this information to the database?

Comment: The answer is undefined while we don't have the full picture. You cannot reliably compare timestamps with unknown time zone - unless you know at least that both are in the same time zone.

Comment: Even if in the same time zone there’s a corner case where comparison will give the wrong result, but there’s nothing we can do about it: When there’s an overlap on the time line (think when summer time, DST, ends), times repeat, and we don’t know exactly how to interpret them. Can you live with getting a few log lines too many or too few in this case?

Comment: *logs which are greater than this time* Log from the future??

Comment: `select 'January 20, 2021 5:26:19 pm'::timestamp; 2021-01-20 17:26:19`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the timezone, use a zone-less timestamp, which postgres supports:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ...
    LOGGED_AT TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    ...
)
```